# Python selenium sendkeys element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to use the sendKeys() function but I keep getting the error "Element not interactable" and I don`t know why. When I use the pyautogui function press() instead of sendKeys() it works just fine

The Code

```
import pyautogui
import time

print('started')

web=webdriver.Chrome()
web.get('https://pt.symbolab.com/')

time.sleep(10)

expression = '2+2'
formXpath = web.find_element_by_id('main-input')
formXpath.click()

time.sleep(10)

formXpath.send_keys(expression)
##pyautogui.press('2') this line works

input = input('Quer parar o programa?')
if input=='s':
    exit()
```

[My terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kVH0.png)

Comment: Have you had a look at my answer? kindly upvote and accept if it helped

Answer (score 0):

The below code works. I use a webdriverwait to wait for the main-input to appear, and the main differences compared to your code is that i click on the span with ID `main-input` but the `send_keys` event is sent to the textarea child being a grandchild. You can't send_keys to a `span`tag.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver_path = '<YOUR DRIVER PATH>'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)


expression = '2+2'
driver.get('https://pt.symbolab.com/')
span = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-input"))
)
textarea = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"main-input\"]/span[1]/textarea"))
    )
span.click()
textarea.send_keys(expression)
```